# Use query string in URL or use multiple URL?

Tags: reactjs, web

If I want to display many posts in my web application but every post have its own type and I want to display each type in single page so, What's the best method to do that? Is put all all posts in one url and use query string to filter the posts upon the type and display it in the page?

For example : `axios.get('/posts?type =sport')`

Or I have to put every single type in separate Url

For example: `axios.get('/posts/sport')`

Also one more question please?
use one reducer to manage every posts or create one reducer for each post type?

Comment: There's no "best" mechanism. Re: totally unrelated question; depends. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a dynamic route to every new type.
Ex:
'/transaction' -> component-1
'/transaction/:type' -> component-any (multiple)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

I can imagine you have a web API of some sort serving a URL `/posts`. You want to consume that endpoint from your web application, and you are using axios to do that. I can assume you are using JSON to return that data. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now that the basic information is "clear", what data you serve from the endpoint, and how it is requested from the client is up to you. Do you want to ask the server what types are there first, and then do one AJAX request per type? Ok. Do you want to serve all posts independent of their type? Ok. Do you want to accept POST data in your controller so you can filter the results before returning a response? Ok.

If you are looking for a more specific answer, you must give more details, or specify more. But I hope I could be of help.

**Edit: complete answer.**

If you want to filter the results, you have to send some additional data in your POST request, in this case, your post type. In axios, this could be done like this:

```
axios.post('https://example.com/posts', {
    type: 'sports'
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

You can obviously get the "type" value from a select input, other variable, even the current router page. I don't know your exact setup, but you can always come back and ask ;)

THEN, in your API controller you have to get that POST parameter `type`, and use it to filter the results. Again, I don't know your exact setup, but for MySQL if would be a `WHERE` statement in your query, or similar.

Comment: Yes I use axios and I receive JSON u are right and yes I want to receive the posts independently upon its type. My point is if the user click on sport page he will see posts with sport types only

Comment: There you go! If you need additional advice, please come back with some more details about your code and we will be willing to help ;)

Comment: You are welcome! Please remember to mark the question as answered to help other people too!